# Getting wrong formatted date value from sap.m.DateTimeInput()

Tags: sapui5

**`Openui5 version working on: 1.38.4`**

```
 wk_start_ts=new sap.m.DateTimeInput({type:"DateTime", 
                layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({linebreak: false,span: "L6 M6 S6"}),
                dateValue: new Date(1468845873851),                                                     
                valueFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                visible : true,


        displayFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}).placeAt("body");

        var oButton1 = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            text : "Button",
            tooltip : "This is a test tooltip",
            press : function() {alert(wk_start_ts.getValue());}
        });
        oButton1.placeAt("body");

For example :
Expected data bound by default is 18/7/2016 18:56
Expected output is 18/7/2016 18:56
Actual Output : 07/18/2016 6:56 PM
```

`Note:` If I change value and then press button then I get expected date value.

Here is an example bin (https://jsbin.com/doxoro/edit?js,output).

**Added a screenshot from browser tested upon i.e. Google Chrome**

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me, the output is the expected if I change or not the input! Maybe you should test (if did not yet) in other browser... I'm using the Chrome.

Comment: I using chrome too but the output is faulty.See the screen shot too in the question.

Comment: Anyway the DateTimeInput is deprecated. Instead, you should use sap.m.DatePicker, sap.m.TimePicker or sap.m.DateTimePicker controls.

Comment: True but the same is the case with `sap.m.DateTimePicker` but  thing is in it supports backward compatibility and `DateTimeInput ` uses `DateTimePicker` internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged a bit and it appears that it processes the settings by **for (property in settings)** clause. So in your particular fragment dateValue is processed before any formatting options. And I would suggest to place dateValue at the end of the settings object:

```
wk_start_ts=new sap.m.DateTimeInput({type:"DateTime", 
                layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({linebreak: false,span: "L6 M6 S6"}),
                valueFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                visible : true,


                displayFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
                dateValue: new Date(1468845873851)                                                     
         }).placeAt("body");

        var oButton1 = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            text : "Button",
            tooltip : "This is a test tooltip",
            press : function() {alert(wk_start_ts.getValue());}
        });
        oButton1.placeAt("body");
```